# Android deeplink doesn't work with '#' character in the url

Tags: android, deeplink

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/hostName" android:pathPattern="/..*common/channeldetail/..*" />


        </intent-filter>
```

this is my intent filter in one acitivty in andoridmanifest.xml 
My deeplink url is which works fine: https://abc.xyz.com/pqr/Web_spf/MOBILE/common/channeldetail/team000000000204586

Now My new deeplink url which doesn't work is : 
https://abc.xyz.com/pqr/Web_spf/MOBILE/app/me#common/channeldetail/team000000000204586

To support this new deeplink i change my intent filter to this :

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/hostName" android:pathPattern="/..*#common/channeldetail/..*" />
```

These deeplinks work with this new intent filter  :
https://abc.xyz.com/pqr/Web_spf/MOBILE/app/common/channeldetail/team000000000204586 
https://abc.xyz.com/pqr/Web_spf/MOBILE/meabccommon/channeldetail/team000000000204586 
**https://abc.xyz.com/pqr/Web_spf/MOBILE/app/me%23common/channeldetail/team000000000204586**

My question here is if '#' character is replaced with its encoded value %23 in the deeplink url, then android is able to detect the deeplink(shows open with prompt when tapped on url) but it doesn't detect my deeplink if '#' character is kept as it is, My  deeplinks will have '#' character and not its encoded value.

I tried to put '%23' in the deeplink pattern but it doesn't work

Comment: When posting/publishing deep links you must encode them.

Comment: Yes but i'm looking for a way to create such pattern that can work with urls having '#' character intact

Comment: The `#` character is the fragment delimiter, and therefore is not part of the path.

Comment: Do you know if  there's any way it can be made a part of the path?